# preg_match help

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm using preg_match for the first time but I'm stuck even before I got some code...

With the help from [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) I have figured out that I need to use this expression:

```
/\(.*M\)\s.*?:/gm
```

What I need help with is how I gonna use this to place`<b></b>`around the matched text.

Gratefull for help.

Comment: What are you trying to match?

Comment: @umop: "(8:00:36 PM) diggan:" The expression I'll use is the one posted in the Q.

Comment: I have ths problem, can you help me, please?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236653/preg-match-all-find-only-the-firt-occurence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$output = preg_replace('%\(.*M\)\s.*?:%', '<b>$0</b>', $input);
```

If you're working in PHP, you'd be better off using this online tester:

http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/

RegExr is a Flex app; the regex engine is the same, but the code used to invoke it is very different.  For example (as Matthew pointed out), there's no `g` flag; you would use the `preg_match_all` method instead.  Remember to add regex delimiters (I used `%`); I'm always forgetting those.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/\(.*M\)\s.*?:/', $input, $matches);
$output = "<b>$matches[0]</b>";
```

There is no `g` flag in PCRE, and I don't think you need multiline, because you're not using ^ or $.

Comment: I don't think that code outputs <b>(8:00:36 PM) diggan:</b> cause I can't find any  <b> in your code...

Comment: @Victor, this is the first time you said anything about `<b>`.  Modify your question and state what the input and output should be.