# preg_match_all find only the firt occurence

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I created this regexp but finds only the first occurrence, where am I wrong?

```
$pattern = '/\\[h-imagegallery id=([0-9,]+)\\]/';
$subject = 'ueihui [h-imagegallery id=4,55] jwff [h-imagegallery id=425]';    

print_r($matches);
```

the result is:

Array
(
    [0] => [h-imagegallery id=4,55]
    [1] => 4,55
)

Comment: You're not calling any `preg_*` function in the code you shared. Please show ALL relevent code.

Comment: Given your output, it looks to me like it found two matches. [0] is the first one, and [1] is the second. what output are you expecting? And it would help if you showed your actual code and the actual output.

Comment: preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches) works as you expect, where is the problem ?

Comment: I copied your code, put `preg_match_all( $pattern, $subject, $matches);` in the space and I got what I assume you wanted... array key `1` contains all the ids... sure you've got your syntax correct?

Comment: Indeed. `[1] => Array ( [0] => 4,55 [1] => 425 )`